# Why download popup window in browser not showing up when using JAX-RS v.s. standard servlet?

Tags: java, excel, rest, servlets, jax-rs

When I try using `standard servlet approach`, in my browser the popup window shows up asking me whether to open .xls file or save it.

I tried the exactly same code via `JAX-RS` and **the browser popup won't show up somehow.** Has anyone encounter this?

**JAX-RS way that won't display popup:**

```
@Path("excellaTest")
public class ExcellaTestResource {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public ExcellaTestResource() {
    }


    @Path("horizontalProcess")
    @GET
    //@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    @Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public void getProcessHorizontally() {
        try {

            URL templateFileUrl = this.getClass().getResource("myExcelTemplate.xls");
            String templateFilePath = URLDecoder.decode(templateFileUrl.getPath(), "UTF-8");
            String outputFileDir = "MasatoExcelHorizontalOutput";
            ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
            ReportBook outputBook = new ReportBook(templateFilePath, outputFileDir, ExcelExporter.FORMAT_TYPE);

            ReportSheet outputSheet = new ReportSheet("myExcelSheet");
            outputBook.addReportSheet(outputSheet);

            reportProcessor.addReportBookExporter(new OutputStreamExporter(response));
            reportProcessor.process(outputBook);

            System.out.println("done!!");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return;
    }


}//end class


class OutputStreamExporter extends ReportBookExporter {

    private HttpServletResponse response;

    public OutputStreamExporter(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    //ReportProcessor output()
    //This method is call when ReportProcessor process() is invoked.
    //The Workbook from POI API can be used to write to stream

    @Override
    public void output(Workbook book, BookData bookdata, ConvertConfiguration configuration) throws ExportException {

        //TODO write to stream
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=masatoExample.xls");
            book.write(response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().close();
            System.out.println("booya!!");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}//end class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What JAX-RS framework are you using?

My guess is that your code doesn't work, because you are returning void. The framework you are using probably recognizes void as **HTTP 204 No Content.** This causes browser to skip the actual response body and to ignore conntent-disposition header.

As I already wrote you in a parallel thread: try to returning Response object. You can put either OutputStream or byte[] as entity as set the content-disposition header.

Comment: I didn't know there is more than one JAX-RS framework. I am using one that comes with NetBean 6.9 + GlassFish v3 bundle. So I'm generating JAX-RS service file using NetBean.

Comment: Ok, just fyi: you are using Jersey. There are more frameworks that support JAX-RS: Apache Wink, CXF, RestEasy and Restlet.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used class level injection for a jax-rs service. I suggest one of 2 solutions.

1) Try injecting the request and response as method arguments.

2) Output your file to a byte array output stream and return a byte array from your method instead of void.